# I want to deploy Node.js & React.js projects in same domain and server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, deployment, web-deployment

As per my Title, I want to deploy Node.js & React.js projects in the same domain and server.

Basically, I want to host the application on cloudways server. https://www.cloudways.com/

I try to host there but due to the same domain action, it is not working as working in the local environment.

1. Front-end screenshot with package.json script structured(React.js): https://prnt.sc/xT4NAPxt0S99
2. Back-end screenshot(Node.js): https://prnt.sc/mSg_H4O6prF0

*The given screenshot is from a local machine.*

As you see here https://prnt.sc/xT4NAPxt0S99 we are using `npm run build` and after doing the build, we move that folder to the server folder and `run npm i && nodemon index.js`. It is working well in a single domain or IP in the local server well. But when I do the same process on a live server, it is not working.

Why I am using cloudways server?

- For this, I don't need to install and set up MySQL, Node modules, PHP, and other things. Cloudways is doing all things when we create a cloud server.

`npm i` don't need to run this company on a server.

Comment: You probably shouldn't [delete the same question from two hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73206405/i-want-to-deploy-node-js-react-js-projects-in-domain-and-server) only to ask exactly the same question.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. There was some mistake. So now it is modified as compared to the deleted one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I hope, the given screenshot is enough to understand the code structure. 
Front-end: https://prnt.sc/xT4NAPxt0S99
Back-end: https://prnt.sc/mSg_H4O6prF0
And build process is explained in question.